# Integrate SoapUI plugin with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, groovy, jenkins

Hi StackExchange community,

I encountered the following issue:
I am creating a plugin for SoapUI to preload some tasks. I am required to get some properties, which were defined as global properties.

In groovy, you get a global property as follows:

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "remotePath" )
```

In my java plugin as follows:

```
TestProperty tp = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getGlobalProperties().getProperty("remotePath");
        if (tp == null ) return "";
        return tp.getValue();
```

This is working for my local installation of SoapUI, but within Jenkins, only the first method is working.

Some infos:
Local SoapUI Version: 4.6.1
Jenkins SoapUI Version: 4.5.1
Jenkins Version: 1.509.3
Maven Version: UnixMaven 3.0.4

I don't give POM information, I don't think it's necessary because it works if I access the global property inside a groovy script.

Comment: Include the error (run-time I guess) that you receive when the call to the second method does not work. I expect that you will have to go through the Jenkins log files/console output to locate the RT error and that ultimately you will need to add a SoapUi JAR file to the Jenkins classpath.

Comment: There is no error, it just returnes NULL, and getting all properties: Map <String, TestProperty> has nothing in it, but two values are defined. SoapUI log method is working, the beforeRun method I implemented works, so it can't be due to missing SoapUI JAR file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the "problem". It seems, that in jenkins the globalProperties are not available at the point where the plugin is loaded, but they are available when the testrunner starts and my beforeRun method triggers. This is not the same behaviour as local but I found a working solution

Comment: Can you share your solution please ? I'm having same issue with SoapUI Maven project